# This infers to the US 6924742 B2 patent

Tags: patentability

I have some design ideas that I want to bring to life that could potentially save lives. Just like the child seat mats, I want to create a pair one for the parent and the other for the car seat, so when the parent gets up from the mat in their seat, an alarm goes off and the only way to turn off is from the child's mat, thus reminding the parent. I know it isn't much but if I could get in contact with the inventor for the patent US 6924742 B2 I think we could have something. I don't know where else to go, and I am tired of seeing children die each year. if we can have fancy phones why cant there be a device to prevent deaths of children?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused of what you're asking here. It sounds like you want to get a patent on your idea using mats instead of the original patent's seatbelts? I fear this post will count as a public disclosure and will likely have a negative effect on your patentability.